# No keyboard input on Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have MacOS Big Sur 11.4 and I have been using Visual Studio Code 1.57. Since the last reboot, I cannot type anything in VS Code. I disabled all the add-ons, then restarted but still not luck.

When I type something in VS Code, it gets typed in whatever app was open before VS Code. So for example, if I have the browser open and I open VS Code, and I try to type anything, it starts getting typed into the browser. If I open from the terminal, it starts getting typed into the terminal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still have the zip file of vscode? If you do, then reinstall it. Also, for once uninstall all the extensions.